# How to sum and join if we have column array

Tags: mysql

I have table jeans like this

[image]

table bahanbenang

[image]

I try to join jeans and bahan benang and sum bahanbenang.biaya  with this query

```
SELECT 
    jeans.id_jeans, jeans.id_benang, 
    SUM(bahanbenang.biaya) AS total
FROM 
    jeans
JOIN 
    bahanbenang ON bahanbenang.id_benang = jeans.id_benang
GROUP BY 
    jeans.id_jeans
```

and display

[image]

in the last row (id_jeans 7) should have total = 302342 beacause in column `id_benang` have 2 (1, 2) values = 1 & 2, 1 with biaya =232342, and 2 with biaya =70000

How to sum with column array?

Comment: sql column/field should not contain two values, id_benang will contain atomic value i.e either 1 or 2 at a time, then your query will work properly.

Comment: but I need id_benang can save more than one value .
do you have solution so that value in last row =  302342

Comment: @faza No. You need to see normalization.